# Get list of object in the swagger API response section

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi-generator

I am using Open API 3.0 to generate the code.

Below is Open API specification:

spec.yml:

```
            openapi: 3.0.0
        info:
          version: 1.0.0
          title: Store API
          description: A store API to get store and related department information
          termsOfService: http://www.***.com/xml,
          contact:
            name: MTAMP Support,
            url: http://www.****.com/xml,
            email: mtamp@mt.com
        paths:
          /api/stores:
            get:
              summary: To get all stores
              tags:
              - Stores
              description: To get all store and department information
              operationId: getStores
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful response
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        type: array
                        items:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StoresDTO'
          /api/stores/{storeId}:
            parameters:
            - in: path
              name: storeId
              required: true
              schema:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              description: Pass a store Id as a parameter
            get:
              summary: To get store infomation based on storeId. When you pass storeId as request related store information along with department will get returned.
              tags:
              - Stores
              description: To get store information based on storeId
              operationId: getStoresById
              x-mtampException:
              - throws com.mt.mtamp.storeservice.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful response
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/StoresDTO'
          /api/stores/{storeId}/regions/{regionId}:
            parameters:
             - in: path
               name: storeId
               required: true
               schema:
                type: integer
                format: int64
               description: Pass a store Id as a parameter
             - in: path
               name: regionId
               required: true
               schema:
                type: integer
                format: int64
               description: Pass a region Id as a parameter
            get:
              summary: To get store infomation based on regionId. When you pass region as request related store information will get returned.
              tags:
              - Stores
              description: To get store information based on regionId.
              operationId: getStoresByRegionId
              x-mtampException:
              - throws com.mt.mtamp.storeservice.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful response
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        type: array
                        items:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/StoresDTO'
          /api/departments/{departmentId}/stores/{storeId}:
             parameters:
               - in: path
                 name: storeId
                 required: true
                 schema:
                   type: integer
                   format: int64
                 description: Pass a department Id as a parameter
               - in: path
                 name: departmentId
                 required: true
                 schema:
                   type: integer
                   format: int64
                 description:  Pass a store Id as a parameter
             get:
              summary: To get department infomation based on storeId. When you pass store Id as request related department information will get returned.
              tags:
              - Departments
              description: To get department information based on storeId.
              operationId: getDepartmentsByStoreId
              x-mtampException:
              - throws com.mt.mtamp.storeservice.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful response
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        type: array
                        items:
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/DepartmentsDTO'
          /api/regions/{regionId}/customer/{customerId}:
            parameters:
            - in: path
              name: customerId
              required: true
              schema:
                type: integer
                format: int32
              description: Pass a customer Id as a parameter
            - in: path
              name: regionId
              required: true
              schema:
                type: integer
                format: int64
              description: Pass a region Id as a parameter    
            get:
              summary: To get region based on customer Id.
              tags:
              - Regions
              description: To get region information based on customer Id.
              operationId: getRegionByCustomerId
              x-mtampException:
              - throws com.mt.mtamp.storeservice.exception.ResourceNotFoundException
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Successful response
                  content:
                    application/json:
                      schema:
                        $ref: '#/components/schemas/RegionsDTO'
        components:
          schemas:
            StoresDTO:
              required:
              - storeName
              - storeLocation
              properties:
                storeId:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  example: 1
                storeName:
                  type: string
                  example: FreshPro
                storeLocation:
                  type: string
                  example: Germany
                departments:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/DepartmentsDTO'
            DepartmentsDTO:
              required:
              - departmentId
              - departmentName
              properties:
                departmentId:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  example: 42
                departmentName:
                  type: string
                  example: Vegetables
                storeId:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  example: 34
            RegionsDTO:
              required:
              - regionId
              - regionName
              properties:
                regionId:
                  type: integer
                  format: int64
                  example: 22
                regionName:
                  type: string
                  example: Fresh Pro
                customerId:
                  type: integer
                  example: 19
                stores:
                  type: array
                  items:
                    $ref: '#/components/schemas/StoresDTO'
```

Generated Code:

```
    @RequestMapping(
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    value = "/api/stores/{storeId}/regions/{regionId}",
    produces = { "application/json" }
)
ResponseEntity<List<StoresDTO>> getStoresByRegionId(
    @Parameter(name = "storeId", description = "Pass a store Id as a parameter", required = true) @PathVariable("storeId") Long storeId,
    @Parameter(name = "regionId", description = "Pass a region Id as a parameter", required = true) @PathVariable("regionId") Long regionId
)throws com.mt.mtamp.storeservice.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
```

Here when I load the swagger for example for service /api/stores/{storesId}/regions/{regionId}, I am seeing the response showing stores and departments object.
This API returns a list of store object but in swagger it showing be single store object.
Can I know how to fix this swagger and Openapi issue

[image]